# Embed gifs are broken

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, gif

```
@client.command()
async def hug(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="E")
    embed.set_image(
        url="https://giphy.com/gifs/lisa-vertudaches-cute-hug-empathy-3oEdv4hwWTzBhWvaU0")
    if member is None:
        await ctx.send("You wanna hug yourself? ")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        return member == ctx.author


    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Ok so the the embed is working but its not sending the gif so why?????????? :))

Comment: Try this link instead: `https://giphy.com/gifs/lisa-vertudaches-cute-hug-empathy-3oEdv4hwWTzBhWvaU0.gif`. The link should always have a proper extension with a format (`.jpg`, `.png`), otherwise the links will not work. Copying the image address could also be a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the link with this one:

`https://media3.giphy.com/media/3oEdv4hwWTzBhWvaU0/giphy.gif?cid=790b76115532c7cbc0da721c844921edc891e5f0f701ff5a&rid=giphy.gif`

I think what might be happening is you set the link to be of the page instead to the gif itself.

Comment: How did u do it?

Comment: You need to right click on the gif file to copy the image address